# Rails redirect_to scoped entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, scope

I've created a controller that lives in the admin scope. So a route to it is expressed by `admin_fx_rates_path` and the url is `localhost:3000/admin/fx_rates`.
The problem is that using the scaffolded controller template the redirec_to in the create or update action it throws an error on the polymorphic module:
`.../gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:142:in`polymorphic_url'`

More specifically, the controller has a `redirect_to @fx_rate`, and Rails is trying to find `fx_rate_url` when it should be searching for `admin_fx_rate_url`. Is there a solution other than changing the code to `redirect_to admin_fx_rate_path(@fx_rate)` ?

Thanks!

routes.rb:

```
  namespace 'admin' do
    resources :users
    resources :fx_rates
  end
```

Comment: Not sure if this solves your problem, but you can also use the following format: `redirect_to [:admin, @fx_rate]`.

Comment: It does solve it! Actually my problem became more clear when I started testing my `:edit` and `:new` views. Both share the same `_form` partial. And while changing it to edit_admin_fx_rate_path(@fx_rate) solved the test for the Edit, it did not solve for the New. With your tip I was able to make them work for both edit and new, but the tests still fail.

Comment: But I'd like it to work without the need to add the scope. So when I call link_to or redirect_to @fx_rate, rails solves it to the scoped link.